# Using the definition of limit to find the derivative of $x \mapsto \sqrt{5x}$

Tags: calculus, limits, derivatives, radicals

> Use the definition of limit to find the derivative of $x \mapsto \sqrt{5x}$.

---

**Answer key:**

*(sqrt(5)) / (2(sqrt(x)))*

**What I have tried:**

[image: What I have tried]

Why won't I get the right answer? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Please do not use pictures for critical portions of your post. Pictures may not be legible, cannot be searched and are not view-able to some, such as those who use screen readers.

Comment: Your work is fine. $\frac{\sqrt{5x}}{2\sqrt x}$ is not correct, but $\frac{\sqrt 5}{2\sqrt x}$ would be.

Comment: @C-RAM Translating all this to latex, for a new user, is a very exquisite punishment in my opinion :)

Comment: You *do* have the right answer.  $\frac 5{2\sqrt{ 5x}} =\frac {\sqrt 5\sqrt 5}{2\sqrt 5\sqrt x} = \frac {\sqrt 5}{2\sqrt x}$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your answer is the same as the one provided by the answer key. Observe:

$\frac{5}{2\sqrt{5x}}=\frac{5}{2\sqrt{5}\sqrt{x}}$

Multiplying by $\frac{\sqrt{5}}{\sqrt{5}}$ yields $\frac{5\sqrt{5}}{10\sqrt{x}}=\frac{\sqrt{5}}{2\sqrt{x}}$ Which is what the answer key provided.

It is strange that the answer key would be in that form given the vast majority of people would have used a process almost identical to yours, getting the same answer, and that you would get the same form if you used the product rule and chain rule. Although it's always a good idea to manipulate your answer if you are confident in your method, especially if it is a multiple-choice test in which your form does not appear.